# Backbonejs Marionette simple chat example

Tags: marionette

As a marionnette beginner, I am trying to make a simple chat application using Collection and CollectionViews.

My collection won't have a fetch method since the messages only come from a particular event.

- In the piece of code below my click event is **not** catched and I wonder why.
- Should the 'send message' event be handled by the Collection view ?
- Do I need to call App.chat.show(MsgListView) to display the messages ?

  ```
  TBox.module("ChatApp", function(ChatApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

  App.addRegions({
      chat: "#chat-messages",
  });

  // Models
  // ------
  MsgEntry = Backbone.Model.extend({});

  // Collections
  // -----------
  MsgCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: MsgEntry
  })

  // VIews
  // -----
  MsgView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
      template: '#chat-entry-template',
  });

  MsgListView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
      itemView: MsgView,

      events: {
            "click #chat-send-btn": "handleNewMessage"
      },

      handleNewMessage: function(data) {
          console.log("CLICK" + data);
      },

  });

  // Init & Finalize
  // ---------------
  ChatApp.addInitializer(function() {
     var msgCollection = new MsgCollection({});
     var msgEntry = new MsgEntry({'msg': 'Hello World'});
     msgCollection.add(msgEntry);
     var msgListView = new MsgListView({collection: msgCollection});

  });
  ```

  });

HTML template

```
 <body>

   <!-- templates -->
    <script type="text/template" id="status-view-template">
        <div>Connecting ...</div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/template" id="chat-entry-template">
        Hello <%= msg =>
    </script>



   <div id="app">
        <div id="sidebar">

            <div id="chat">
                <h3>Chat</h3>
                <div id="chat-messages">
                </div>
                <div id-"chat-input">
                    <input type="text" name="msg" />
                    <button id="chat-send-btn">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- main -->
        <div id="page">

        </div>

    <div>

</body>
```

Comment: can you include the basic HTML that you're using for this app, and the "chat-entry-template" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I made it work with  App.chat.show(msgListView);

Also the events hash only takes car of the ItemView events, not other dom events.

```
// Init & Finalize
// ---------------
ChatApp.addInitializer(function() {
   App.vent.trigger("app:started", "ChatApp");

   var msgCollection = new MsgCollection([{foo :'bar', foo: 'lol'}]);
   var msgListView = new MsgListView({collection: msgCollection});

   // render and display the view
   App.chat.show(msgListView);
});
```